# The best way to store data in java with more dimensions?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I have some input like :

```
  package 1 : org.orchestr.something  version= 5.1.3

      uses = org.do.resource   ; version= 1.2.1
      uses = org.test.summer   ; version= 1.5.2


  package 2 : fr.test.something  version= 5.1.3

      uses = com.java.rest     ; version= 1.0.1
      uses = org.osgi.summer   ; version= 1.4.2

  ....
```

So in this data I have set of packages defined by their version and bunch others packages that they use within a specific version, and i want to know with is the best way/ practical way to store this kind of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could model it as a map of artifacts :

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Artifact {
    private String name;
    private String version;

    public Artifact(String name, String version) {
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Artifact that = (Artifact) o;
        return version.equals(that.version) &&
                name.equals(that.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(version, name);
    }
}
```

And here would be a usage of this :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Artifact, Set<Artifact>>  map = new HashMap<>();


        Set<Artifact> dependencies = new HashSet<>();
        dependencies.add(new Artifact("org.do.resource ", "1.2.1"));
        dependencies.add(new Artifact("org.test.summer ", "1.5.2"));

        map.put(new Artifact("org.orchestr.something", "5.1.3"), dependencies);
    }
```

I had to override `equals` and `hashcode` methods for `Artifact` class because objects of this class will be used as keys in `HashMap`.
If you want to also support package version just add such field to `Artifact` class and add apropriate constructor, getters, setters and modify `equals` and `hashcode` methods accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you intend to represent some graph like structure.

A first naive implementation could/would be using specific classes, like `Package` and `Entry` where a Package probably has a list/set of of `Entry` objects (and an Entry has a name + version string).

Of course, as you are in the end intend to create some sort of graph, you probably should look into solutions such as [graphql](https://www.graphql-java.com/), too.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work, assuming there's one-level of nested dependency in your case:

A base `Artifact` class:

```java
  class Artifact {
    protected String name;
    protected String version;

    public Artifact(String name, String version) {
      this.name = name;
      this.version = version;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
      return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
      this.version = version;
    }
  }
```

A `Package` class that extends `Artifact` and adds another parameter `uses`:

```java
class Package extends Artifact {

    public Package(String name, String version, List<Artifact> uses) {
      super(name, version);
      this.uses = uses;
    }

    private List<Artifact> uses;

    public List<Artifact> getUses() {
      return uses;
    }

    public void setUses(List<Artifact> uses) {
      this.uses = uses;
    }
  }
```

You can then store it as a `List` or `Map` as needed.

Example of using in a `Map`:

```java
    Map<String, Package> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("package1", new Package("org.orchestr.something", "5.1.3", Arrays.asList(
        new Artifact("org.do.resource", "1.2.1"),
        new Artifact("org.test.summer", "1.5.2")))
    );

    map.put("package2", new Package("fr.test.something", "5.1.3", Arrays.asList(
        new Artifact("com.java.rest", "1.0.1"),
        new Artifact("org.osgi.summer", "1.4.2")))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The package and uses data look equal. So i would use a map:

```
class Uses { private path, version; }
Map<Uses, Set<Uses>> data;
```

The packages are the keys, the used dependencies are elements of the value.

Comment: But i need to store also the version of the packages and I could have the access to get it also !

Comment: You asked about a data structure, i gave you one. The version is stored in the private field version of class Uses. Your IDE will automatically write constructors, getters, and setters, if you don’t want to do it yourself.